# onbeforeunload unless either the save or submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the `onbeforeunload` pop-up to appear unless I click on the submit or the save button. Any ideas?

So far I have this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.PreventNavigation = function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function ()   {
    return "Please save your work before navigating from this page";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
Drupal.behaviors.PreventNavigation = function() {
  var clicked = false;
  $('#edit-save').click(function() {
    clicked = true;
  });
  $('#edit-submit-application').click(function() {
    clicked = true;
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit() {
   if (!clicked) {
     return "Please Save your work";
   }
  }
}
```